# How to maintain hover effect after onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a `div` named `#wrapper` that has an `hover` event, in which it changes its `background-color` property.

Inside this `wrapper` I have some text that has `opacity: 0` and when I click on the `container`, this text will be show (`opacity: 1`).

I would like that when the `#wrapper` div will be clicked, it will stay with the same colour that it has when it is hovered. If you click again, the text will disappear and the default colour of the `#wrapper` will come again (from its parent) and the `hover` effect should work again.

The problems comes here, because if I click on the `#wrapper` the hover effect does not come anymore.

I guess it is something related about [specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of inline elements (when I insert it via `Javascript`) but I do not have any idea about how to still handle the `hover` event after the `onclick` event has been triggered.

Here is the code I have by the moment:

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  
  container.onclick = function(){
      if(text.style.opacity == 0){
       text.style.opacity = 1;
        wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      else{
       text.style.opacity = 0;
        wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
      }
  };
}
```

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
}

#container{
    background-color: orange;
}

#wrapper{
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#wrapper:hover{
  background-color: red;
}

#container p{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p id="text">Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I handle the `onclick` event to not override the `hover` event when the `#wrapper` div has the default `background-color` (the second time you `onclick` on the `#wrapper`)?

**Note: I only want to use Javascript.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `wrapper.style.backgroundColor = '';`

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

  container.onclick = function(){
    if(text.style.opacity == 0){
      text.style.opacity = 1;
      wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else{
      text.style.opacity = 0;
      wrapper.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
  };
}
```

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
}

#container{
    background-color: orange;
}

#wrapper{
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#wrapper:hover{
  background-color: red;
}

#container p{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p id="text">Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I notice now that I am not referencing `wrapper` to any element as @soloughlin3 points me out in his answer. I am really new on Javascript so, why it is being executed correctly?

Comment: @Error404: You should add a reference, updated my answer with that, though it appears most browsers add each id in the document to its global scope, [chech this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6853267/2827823), hence it works.

Comment: Yes, on my real project I had it. Just a mistake when re-writing it here but now I was confused about how it could be working. I also guess that it matches each ID with a variable with the same name but could not find anything about that. Now I am secure. Thanks for the link and for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare what `wrapper` is, try using this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var container = document.getElementById('container'),
        text = document.getElementById('text'),
        wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

  container.onclick = function(){
      if(text.style.opacity == 0){
        text.style.opacity = 1;
        wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      else{
        text.style.opacity = 0;
        wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "";
      }
  };
}
```